# Ordering of a sentence

Tags: word-order

Which of these two sentences are wrong?

> **A:** She understood a few minutes later the explanation
>
> **B:** A few minutes later she understood the explanation

Comment: I recommend you read through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for some very useful tips on formatting your questions.

Answer (score 5):

Your first (with the adverbial "a few minutes later" between the verb and its object) is definitely **not** idiomatic, and immediately suggests something written by a non-English speaker.

The adverbial can come at the beginning (your second suggestion), or at the end:  "She understood the explanation a few minutes later".

Comment: True, but is there any kind of "rule" here? There doesn't seem to be a problem with the adverbial element coming either before or after the "object" in *She easily understood the text* and *She understood the text easily.* Is it just (or mainly) a matter of *how long* the adverbial element is?

Comment: What, @FumbleFingers? Neither of your examples has the adverbial coming between the verb and its object. Or are you asking about whether it can come between the subject and the predicate? There it does depend on the type of adverbial; for example, time and place can't usually be interposed there.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't thinking clearly. But yeah, that's the kind of thing I was getting at. *Time/place adverbials* can't usually be interposed between subject & predicate, whereas *adverbs of manner* often can.