# The order of the verb and adverbial phrase in question

Tags: word-order, questions, adverbial-phrases

Which order is correct?

- How much milk is **in the fridge** *left*?
- How much milk is *left* **in the fridge**?

Comment: "How much milk is left in the fridge?" is correct. In your example, "is left" means "remains" in the carton.

Comment: **Adverbial phrases** come either at the beginning of the sentence or at the end. [Answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198685/ordering-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, because it depends how you interpret the sentence. What is the object? If you think it is

> How much milk is in the fridge?

Then modified by *left*, I can see where there would be confusion. However, it's actually:

> How much milk is left?

Modified by *in the fridge*. The idea of something "being left" is pretty much a set phrase that can be treated as a phrasal verb, though I believe it's really a passive construction using *to leave* in the same sense as "he left her at the station". Thus, it is *in the fridge* that comes last.

Now, *milk in the fridge* can be used as a noun phrase, so you could grammatically say:

> How much milk in the fridge is left?

But a native speaker never would say that. It's always:

> How much milk is left in the fridge?